# Google Spreadsheets function to copy array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrays

Is there an array function to copy an array? I use the workaround `=TRANSPOSE(TRANSPOSE(A1:A30))` currently.

An example of when this is useful: you have a worksheet of raw data, and another worksheet with formulas applied to those values.

Doing it this way means that if a row is inserted in the first spreadsheet, it will be inserted in the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

Instead of `=TRANSPOSE(TRANSPOSE(A1:A30))` consider to use `={A1:A30}` as it's shorter.

## Long answer

An alternative to `ARRAYFORMULA` is the use of `embedded arrays` also named

- inline arrays
- literal arrays
- array parameters
- "your own arrays"

### Example of embedded array of constants

```
={"A","B";1,2}
```

[image: Literal Array]

```
={A1:B2;D1:E2;G1:H2}
```

### Example of embedded array of non-adjacent ranges.

[image: Embedded array]

It's worth to say that for spreadsheets with regional settings that use:

- `.` as the decimal separator should use `,` as the column delimiter
- `,` as the decimal separator should use `\` as the column delimiter

In both cases use `;` as the row delimiter.

## Reference

[Using arrays in Google Sheets - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

Answer (score 4):

An `ARRAYFORMULA` would cover that. You can reference a range of columns like so:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!A:H)
```

Complete columns are taken in to account, thus if something gets inserted on sheet 1, it will be included in sheet 2.