# How to Aggregate and Pivot Simultaneously With Google Sheets Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Hey I am trying to transform a table from this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

Basically for each "Type" I want the totals for the different values for "Exists" which right now is just TRUE and FALSE.

But I can only get to this so far:

[image]

I did that using the following `QUERY`

```
SELECT B, C, COUNT(C) GROUP BY B,C
```

I know the next step requires a `PIVOT` but I'm having some fundamental misunderstanding about how `PIVOT` works to get anywhere. If you could help me out with some understanding and not just give me the answer it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QUERY function's query statement doesn't allow using the same column to group, aggregate, and pivot data.

The workaround is to add an additional column that is a duplicate of the data in C. This can be done in the range or in the formula.

#### Duplicate in Range

This formula requires creating a new data column D that is a duplicate of C:

```
=QUERY(A1:D7,"SELECT B, COUNT(C) GROUP BY B PIVOT D", 1)
```

#### Duplicate in Formula

In this approach the duplication is done using an  [embedded/inline array](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/80611) within the formula therefore it doesn't require changing the source data. You must use [Col1 notation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91919/) with this approach. eg. Col1, Col2, Col3, instead of A, B, C.

Example using your data range, A1:C7:

```
=QUERY({A1:C7, C1:C7}, "SELECT Col2, COUNT(Col3) GROUP BY Col2 PIVOT Col4", 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I did that:

=QUERY(QUERY(A7:C7;"SELECT B, C, COUNT(C) GROUP BY B,C");"SELECT Col1, sum(Col3) group by Col1 pivot Col2")

I'm just using your first result as the range of the query function that I add

Comment: The accepted answer does it with one query. Is there any additional benefit to your approach? Also your ranges appear incorrect. Have you tested this formula?