# Can someone help me with this google sheets group by query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have 3 columns. I would like to sum up the total revenue of `Revenue by month` in `Dec-2019` (As you can see there are 2). And also sum up the `Net profit by month`(As you can see there are 2), last but not least also `Net profitability by month`.

The formula I've been trying is

```
=query('Observations Table - Live'!$A$3:$H,"select A, sum(B), group by C")
```

```
Metric                      Value              Period

Revenue by month            $1000              Dec-2019
Revenue by month            $2000              Dec-2019
Net profit by month         $500               Dec-2019
Net profit by month         $600               Dec-2019
Net profitability by month  $100               Dec-2019
Net profitability by month  $75                Dec-2019
```

The outcome I would like to have is this

```
Period           Revenue by month     Net profit by month   Net profitability by month
Dec-2019         $3000                $1100                 $175
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that you to make some changes to your original formula

Try

```
=query(A:C,"select C, sum(B) where B is not null group by C pivot A")
```

- I'm using A:C instead `'Observations Table - Live'!$A$3:$H` because the sample data in the body of the question includes only three columns.
- Also I'm using `where B is not null` to filter all the rows where B is blank.

Related

- [How to Aggregate and Pivot Simultaneously With Google Sheets Query](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/117061/88163)

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage